# Writing a HTML5 Websocket client without socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, websocket

I have a simple nodeJS server, that listens to requests at port 8080. Can I use HTML5 websockets instead of socket.io on the client side to listen to the server response? If so, what would that code look like? Here is my nodeJS server code.

```
var http = require('http');

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
  request.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
    response.statusCode = 400;
    response.end();
  });
  response.on('error', function(err) {
    console.error(err);
  });
  if (request.method === 'GET' && request.url === '/echo') {
    request.pipe(response);
  } else {
    response.statusCode = 404;
    response.end();
  }
}).listen(8080);
```

Comment: You need a webSocket server implementation that implements the webSocket protocol, encryption and data packet format.  There are numerous implementations on NPM.

Comment: ok..thanks. I will look into it

Comment: `ws` is lean and mean server-side socket lib without all the socket.io features, but with a lot more performance. The browser's native websocket API is close to the basic socket.io usage; event-based handlers for a few built-in events.